# Keras can't be imported in Virtual Env

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv, keras

Any idea how this could be fixed?

```
mona@pascal:~$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
mona@pascal:~$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
mona@pascal:~$ workon cv2
(cv2) mona@pascal:~$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'keras'
```

UPDATE:

```
$ sudo pip install keras
The directory '/home/mona/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mona/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting keras
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading Keras-1.2.0.tar.gz (167kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 174kB 2.1MB/s 
Collecting theano (from keras)
  Downloading Theano-0.8.2.tar.gz (2.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.9MB 346kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from theano->keras)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.11 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from theano->keras)
Installing collected packages: theano, keras
  Running setup.py install for theano ... done
  Running setup.py install for keras ... done
Successfully installed keras-1.2.0 theano-0.8.2
(cv2) mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'keras'

(cv2) mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build$ sudo pip3 install keras
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): keras in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): theano in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from theano->keras)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from theano->keras)
Cleaning up...
(cv2) mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade keras
Requirement already up-to-date: keras in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: theano in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from theano->keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from theano->keras)
Cleaning up...
(cv2) mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `pip freeze` inside and outside of the virtualenv?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are running `pip` with `sudo` from the virtualenv. This temporarily makes you root, resets all the environment variables that are set by virtualenvwrapper and thus installs the packages system-wide instead in the virtualenv.

This should work better:

```
workon cv2
pip install keras tensorflow
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible when creating `cv2` environment, you did not create it with `--system-site-packages` flag?
If not, you can always `pip install keras` inside the virtualenv.

Comment: please have a look at the update. Unfortunately it didn't work!

Comment: Using a virtualenv with `--system-site-package` kind of defeats the purpose, no?

Comment: @HaraldNordgren `--system-site-packages` lets you use packages installed on your system, but you may still install new packages in the environment. This is useful in cases where you want to install numpy once systemwide, but then quickly iterate on different packages that depend on numpy.  @mona-jalal your update still does not show how you created the virtual environment. But @HaraldNordgren's suggestion above should work. However, since you tried sudo first, there might be some files your used cannot rewrite anymore, so I suggest creating a new environment (cv3 maybe) and trying there.